# Why is there a big gap between the moves and play buttons in the replayer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, pgn-viewer, design

I have recently noticed an annoying feature of the replayer. No matter the amount of moves, there always a big gap between them and the play buttons. Here is a screenshot of a chosen [example](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/35482/15543).

[image]

Why is this so? It is rather annoying to have to scroll past it all the time. Is there away to fix this so it formats itself accordingly with the move amount? Of course, if an answer has many moves, it will default to the built in limit such as in [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/15550/15543) with a long stalemate problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. Glorfindel was correct - it was happening because the chess player is not really built optimally for responsive design. Now below a certain width breakpoint, the move will show up below the board and not beside it.

---

> `1. e4 e6`
> Load it in a narrow screen
> Moves beneath the board!

Reducing the zoom function to 50% for the given example proves that this has been fixed.

[image]

Comment: I still have this issue on mobile

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the responsive design. For me, at full browser width (1440px) it shows normally:

[image]

and the problem only appears when I make the window a bit smaller:

[image]

It could be fixed by removing the fixed `height` of the `moves` element, then it will look like this:

[image]

but I'm not experienced enough in responsive design to tell whether that's the best solution. So I'm tagging this as [status-review](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review) to have Stack Exchange's developers to have a look.

Comment: Useful research. And it should be borne in mind that not everyone has the money to buy (or the space to put) a huge screen, and not everyone has keen enough eyesight to cope with 1440p on a normal-sized one.